# is this true or false.. im really confused...∀ x ∈ R ∃! y ∈ R ∋ x + y = 0.

Tags: logic

$$∀ x ∈ R ∃! y ∈ R ∋ x + y = 0.$$
$$\text{For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x+y=0$.}$$

I consider this statement to be false. But I cannot seem to explain it. Let $x = 2$ and $y = -2$ then the statements is true but when $x = 3$, then the statement becomes false. I have trouble writing down the solution

Comment: If you have a statement you can't seem to make much sense out of, try constructing a few examples to get an idea of what it's saying.

Comment: If $x=3$ then $y=-3$ as the $y$ can change as there is something to be said for the order of the predicates here. If the unique $y$ was first then you'd be correct but $x$ is given before we find the $y$ value.

Answer (score 5):

It might help to translate it into English: "For all x in $\mathbb R$, there is a unique $y$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $x+y=0.$"

So for $x=3$, the statement asserts that the equation $3+y=0$ has a unique solution, which is true. Indeed, for every $x$, there is exactly one $y$ such that $x+y=0$, namely $y=-x$.

So the statement is true.